# npm link inside project's subfolder

Tags: npm, webstorm

This problem seems very specific but I think it is quite interesting to share, as it could help other people in a similar situation.

I am helping in the development of a npm package (let's call it lib). Inside the project's root directory there is a folder called "examples" with mini-projects using the library itself for testing purposes. Those projects can require the package through `npm link` (inside the mini-projects), which is [one of the recommended ways](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) of testing your package without having to continuously rebuild it. The idea here is to keep that folder inside the project.

The issue is that it creates an infinite chain of folders as shown below.

```
-- lib
---- /examples
------ /project1
--------- /node_modules
----------- / lib
------------- /examples
--------------- /project1 <--- see the infinite loop here
------------- ...
----------- ...
------ ...
---- index.js
---- package.json
---- .npmignore
---- ...
```

This recursive linkage messes up with memory and blocks development, specially when working with the WebStorm IDE that loops infinitely while "indexing for files...".

It seems that `npm link` does not consider .npmignore (.gitignore neither) when creating the link. It also does not consider the "files" field if present in the package.json file.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: did you find a solution / workaround for this ?